# Is there any way to trigger monthly glue job after daily glue job?

Tags: workflow, aws-glue

Let's say there are three glue jobs, which are A, B, C
A and B are daily jobs, and C is monthly job.

I want these jobs to be executed following order:

- A(daily) -> B(daily, but only when A succeed) -> C(monthly, but only when A and B succeed)

C should not work when B is failed.

Is there any way to do this easily and safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Glue Workflow. Just create two workflows, one that would have Jobs A and B, running everyday and second workflow with Jobs A,B,C running monthly.

While creating workflows, you can set to run job B or C only when previous job succeeds.
For more information, read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflows_overview.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just one more question, Doesn't it make job A and B to be ran twice?

Comment: The day on which the monthly workflow runs, don't run the daily workflow that day. YOu can set appropriate days using cron expressions.

Comment: Oh using cron expressions!! I forgot that. Thank you so much!!